# JQuery Two dropdowns second submits on load

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, listbox

I have two dropdowns / list boxes, on the first submit, the page queries the database and pulls back possible options.  I am trying to have the second dropdown on load pull back / display results.  But I am going in circles.

JQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('#firstOne').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#secondOne').change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
     });
});
```

CFML

```
 <select id="firstOne" name="filterOne">
  <option value="All">-- Show All --</option>
  <option value="State">State</option>
</select>
<cfif IsDefined( "URL.filter") AND URL.filter NEQ "">
  <cfif URL.filter EQ 'State'>
    <cfquery name="qryState">
      SELECT DISTINCT state FROM Database
    </cfquery>
    <select id="secondOne" name="filterTwo">
      <cfoutput query="qryState">
        <option value="state">state</option>
      </cfoutput>
    </select>
  </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Thanks.

Comment: First, just do one thing at a time.  Get the first select to populate the second.  Next, don't have any code that submits the form other than a submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dan is right, start simple when you're trying to understand what's going on. Place in a submit button in the form.
2. You likely did some renaming before pasting the code here, but since I can't know that for sure, it strikes me as odd that your primary select list is named firstOne and your `cfif` checks url.filter.
3. The code below assumes the identifier value is a nvarchar type. If it's int, change cf_sql_varchar to cf_sql_integer. If you're not familiar with cfqueryparam, look it up. It defends your site against sql injections aimed at altering tables/databases. [Read more.](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam)
4. While here's a sample answer below.. I would do one of two things.

   - I would put each box on it's own page.
   - I would do this with jQuery or Javascript, since it's entirely possible with it. I'll share an implementation I wrote below.

You can try this

```
<form method="post" action="boxes.cfm">
    <select id="firstOne" name="filterOne">
        <option value="All">-- Show All --</option>
        <option value="State">State</option>
    </select>
    <cfif IsDefined("form.firstone") and form.firstone EQ 'State'>
        <cfquery name="qryState">
            SELECT DISTINCT state FROM Database
            WHERE SomethingID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.firstone#">
        </cfquery>
        <select id="secondOne" name="filterTwo">
        <cfoutput query="qryState">
            <option value="state">state</option>
        </cfoutput>
        </select>
    </cfif>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter Data">
</form>
```

HTML for JQuery [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/d02k2zkz/)

```
<div class="prodselectbox">
    <div id="box1">Category:
        <select id="selectcat" name="categoryselected">
            <option value="" class="rhth">Select Type</option>
            <option value="colors">Colors</option>
            <option value="books">Books</option>
            <option value="animals">Animals</option>
            <option value="furniture">Furniture</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">Items: <select id="selectprod" name="articleID">
            <option value="">Select SubType</option>
            <option value="red" class="colors">red</option>
            <option value="blue" class="colors">blue</option>
            <option value="bible" class="books">bible</option>
            <option value="phonebook" class="books">phonebook</option>
            <option value="cat" class="animals">cat</option>
            <option value="dog" class="animals">dog</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectcat').change(function () {
        if ($('option:selected', this).attr('value') == '') {
            $('#box2').hide();
            $('#selectprod option').hide();
        } else {
            if ($('#selectprod option.'+$('option:selected', this).attr('value')).length > 0) {
                $('#selectprod option').hide();
                $('#box2').show();
                $('#selectprod option.'+$('option:selected', this).attr('value')).show();
            } else {
                $('#selectprod option').hide();
                $('#box2').hide();
                alert('No items in category');
            }
        }

    });
    $('#box2').hide();
    $('#selectprod option').hide();
});
```

The way that this works is that the ID of the first select corresponds to the class of the second select.

So you could make your ID of the options of the first select "c#CategoryID#" and make the classes of the options of the second select "c#CategoryID#".